# Moment timezone and DST

Tags: node.js, timezone, momentjs, dst

I am using this code to fetch the GMT difference for a specific time zone:

```
var TimeZone = 'America/New_York';
console.log('GMT Offset  ' + moment().tz(TimeZone).utcOffset().toString());
```

Would this code take the DST into account too?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes, `moment.tz()` is daylight savings aware. The [docs](https://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/using-timezones/parsing-in-zone/) are explicit about it:

> The `moment.tz` constructor takes all the same arguments as the moment constructor, but uses the last argument as a [time zone identifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones).
>   ...
>   This constructor is DST aware, and will use the correct offset when parsing.

```js
var TimeZone = 'America/New_York';
console.log('Winter GMT Offset  ' + moment.tz('2018-12-04', TimeZone).utcOffset()/60);
console.log('Summer GMT Offset  ' + moment.tz('2018-06-04', TimeZone).utcOffset()/60);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-timezone/0.5.23/moment-timezone-with-data-2012-2022.min.js"></script>
```